# JAX RS auto Marshal/Unmarshal List objects inside root objects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I've a method like following in a service class

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response listUsers( 
        @QueryParam("page") @DefaultValue("1") Integer page,
        @QueryParam("sortFields") @DefaultValue("id") String sortFields,
        @QueryParam("sortDirections") @DefaultValue("asc") String sortDirections) {

    PaginatedListWrapper listWrapper = new PaginatedListWrapper<>();
    listWrapper.setCurrentPage(page);
    listWrapper.setSortFields(sortFields);
    listWrapper.setSortDirections(sortDirections);
    listWrapper.setTotalResults(this.countAll());

    int start = (listWrapper.getCurrentPage() - 1) * listWrapper.getPageSize();
    listWrapper.setList(userFacade.findRange(new int[]{start, listWrapper.getPageSize()}));

    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(listWrapper).build();
}
```

my PaginatedListWrapper class like follows

```
public class PaginatedListWrapper {
private Integer currentPage;
private Integer pageSize;
private Integer totalResults;

private String sortFields;
private String sortDirections;
private List list;
```

...

and im getting output like the following

```
Object{ currentPage: 1,  list: Array[2], 0: "net.brac.ict.mis.tup.uplift.business.entities.User[ id=1 ]" 1: "net.brac.ict.mis.tup.uplift.business.entities.User[ id=2 ]" , pageSize: 10,  sortDirections: "asc", sortFields: "id"…}
```

why im not getting the list of users as json object? like array of objects [{}, {}, {} ...]
what im missing here?
other than using jersey or jackson, i want to learn the underneath core stuffs of doing this.
in my maven it just javaee-web-api and eclipselink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `User` entity is annotated with JAXB annotations, you can do basically this much simpler:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Collection<User> listUsers( 
        @QueryParam("page") @DefaultValue("1") Integer page,
        @QueryParam("sortFields") @DefaultValue("id") String sortFields,
        @QueryParam("sortDirections") @DefaultValue("asc") String sortDirections) {

    PaginatedListWrapper listWrapper = new PaginatedListWrapper<>();
    listWrapper.setCurrentPage(page);
    listWrapper.setSortFields(sortFields);
    listWrapper.setSortDirections(sortDirections);
    listWrapper.setTotalResults(this.countAll());

    int start = (listWrapper.getCurrentPage() - 1) * listWrapper.getPageSize();
    return userFacade.findRange(new int[]{start, listWrapper.getPageSize()});
}
```

JAX-RS has a built-in `Collection` `MessageBodyWriter` provider and will map your entity using JAXB accordingly for you. This is how I return all my entities in my JAX-RS services.

Comment: I dont need to return the userlist like you did here, my user is JAXB annotated and its always return right way. I want to push that in a wrapper with other paginated info property and return that. please see the code above..

Comment: Annotate your `PaginatedListWrapper` as well with JAXB annotations if you want JAX-RS to marshal it using JAXB.

Comment: I did that for PaginatedListWrapper but now its showing
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json

I got right output when i use 
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

into my pom 
my question is if the JAXB support is built-in why i need to add jersey-json ?

Comment: Jersey uses JAXB to marshal Objects to XML, as JAXB should. To further add it to JSON, you will need to translate XML to JSON. Most Java EE compliant containers will have json serialization for JAX-RS built-in.

Comment: What JAXB annotation need to use to translate xml to json. Thank you very much for your support so far.

Comment: Whatever you have it's fine. JAX-RS uses a data binding library like Jackson where it translates your JAXB to XML to JSON internally.